# How to form nested objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, treeview

I am trying to dynamically form a nested tree object something like below using JavaScript, can someone please let me know the best way to achieve this?

```
 var contextpath= {
        text: "TreeRoot",
        items: [ {
            text: "subgroup1" ,
            items: [ {
                text: "subgroup2",
                items: [ {
                    text: "subgroup3",
                    items: [ {
                        text: "subgroup4",
                        items: [ {
                            text: "subgroup5"
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    };
```

I have delimited string that I am trying to convert to object (that can be used as dat source for tree component).

var path="TreeRoot|subgroup1|subgroup2";

Trying to implement something like below but with recursion / looping using less number of variables.

```
    var contextpathText= {};
    contextpathText.text ="TreeRoot";

    var childObject={};
    var items=[];
    childObject.text ="subgroup1";
    items.push(childObject);
    contextpathText.items=(items);
```

Comment: Looks like you did OK. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Create this object? What are the parameters? Do you have an array you want to transform to this, you just want to create an `n` deep object like this, or what?

Comment: subgroup2 is a subgroup of subgroup1?

Comment: Yes, subgroup2 is a subgroup of subgroup1. (ie. subgroup1 is the parent of subgroup2)

Comment: You're going to need either more than one string (bad idea), or more than one delimiter (good idea), to define when you are going deeper into the tree, and when you are coming out of that pocket, and back into its parent (or next-child).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a depth counter and to store the current levels of the object you're working with.

```
var obj = {text:''}, parent, child, i = 0;
obj.text = 'TreeRoot';
parent = obj;
while (++i <= 5) {
    if (parent.items === undefined) parent.items = []; // because you don't have an items on the last subgroup you can't put it in the object literal
    child = {text: 'subgroup'+i};
    parent.items.push(child);
    parent = child;
}
parent = child = null; // cleanup
obj;
```

[jsbeautified](http://jsbeautifier.org/) `JSON.stringify(obj)` is now

```
{
    "text": "TreeRoot",
    "items": [{
        "text": "subgroup1",
        "items": [{
            "text": "subgroup2",
            "items": [{
                "text": "subgroup3",
                "items": [{
                    "text": "subgroup4",
                    "items": [{
                        "text": "subgroup5"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

---

Edit For delimited string

```
var path = 'TreeRoot|subgroup1|subgroup2';

var obj = {text:''}, parent, child, levelText = path.split('|').reverse();
obj.text = levelText.pop() || '';
parent = obj;
while (levelText.length > 0) {
    child = {text: levelText.pop()};
    if (!parent.items) parent.items = [];
    parent.items.push(child);
    parent = child;
}
obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Beat me to it, but I went with this code:

```
var contextpath = { text: "TreeRoot", items: []}

var items = contextpath.items;

for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    items.push({ text: "subgroup" + i, items: []});
    items = items[0].items;
}
```

The parent & child nomenclature is definitely clearer, for this sort of thing, but I wanted to show that you didn't have to declare the new object as a variable first, you can just push the object literal.

Whoops, just now noticed that you don't have an items array in your desired structure. My code creates the spare, so you end up with

```
// snip
                text: "subgroup4",
                    items: [ {
                        text: "subgroup5",
                        items: []
                    }]
// etc.
```

Comment: You're very welcome, but Paul S.'s answer more closely matches what you asked for.